# Multiplicative linear model

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear

I am considering the model:

$$
y_t = \beta_0\left(\Pi_{i=0}^{K}x_{i,t}^{\beta_i}\right)\left(\Pi_{j = K+1}^{L}e^{\beta_{j}x_{j,t}}\right)
$$

where we want to have multiplicative effect between variables and linear for the others. My question is the following: in this model, how can we interprate and estimate the coefficients ? I mean we cannot keep the interpretation from the simple linear regression model where the coefficient $\beta_i$ represents the impact of the explanatory variable $x_{i,t}$ on the explained variable $y_t$.

The advantage of a such model is to separate explanatory variables in two sets in order to have something realistic about the model when we should have $y_t = 0$ because in the set of fundamental explanatory variables we have one variable $x_{i,t} = 0$ so there is a kind of  ''interaction" between variables.

Comment: If you take the logs of both sides, it becomes a linear model - linear in $\log x_i$ for the first $K$ terms and linear in the $x_i$ themselves for the remaining $L-K$ terms.

Comment: since you have x^beta, it is not a linear model. IN a linear model, if you want to have multiplicative effect of a variable on the outocme you can just log-transform it.

Comment: @jbowman Yes but this is not the same model using this transformation, so how you interpret the coefficients ?

Comment: @rep_ho I think that it's meet the first comment !

Comment: This model is incompletely specified.  How it is fit and interpreted depends on your probability model for the deviations between the left and right sides.  What is that model?

Comment: The coefficients are *exactly the same* as in the model formulation you've written, so the interpretation is too.  Note also @whuber's comment.

Comment: @whuber  In fact I don't know how to represent the error term since I have to construct a model from real data and I have no prior knowledge on what should be the distribution of this term so should I assume it is normally distributed? To be honest I don't know how it helps to answer my question. I must (surely) be wrong but I see the problem of estimation as a geometric problem clearly and not so from a probability point of view, at least at this stage...

Comment: Start with the log-log model (which is readily fit using ordinary least squares regression) and study the residuals.  But before doing that, please explain what you mean about the zero values: that raises many red flags but it's unclear what you're trying to say.

Comment: @whuber Thank you I will try to explain that. I have $y_t$ that represents the sales of a company and among the explanatory variables we have the distribution of the product sold by the company ($x_{i,t}$), the intuition is that we should have no sales when the distribution of products sold by the company is $0$, however in the linear model it would not be the case since it is an additive model and this is for this reason I seek for a multiplicative model as the one presented in my post.

Comment: That is a very weak reason for selecting a multiplicative model over a linear one.  Moreover, even when theory implies the response must be zero for a determined value of the explanatory variables, forcing the model to behave like that can often distort its behavior everywhere else (see our posts on [no-intercept models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+no+intercept)).  One of the most important things you want your model to capture is the variability of the response, which is why it's often best to begin by studying that.

Comment: @whuber  Thank you for your answer. I think I see the point you try to highlight for me. First I have considered a linear model and studied the residuals, the fit of the model was not good (the residuals are too high on the period considered for the data).  So I should consider a model of the type $ y_t = ln(\beta_0) + \sum_{i=0}^{K}\beta_{i}ln(x_{i,t}) + \sum_{j=K+1}^{L}\beta_{j}x_{j,t} $, is that you called log-log model ?

Comment: Close: the left hand side would, of course, be the *logarithm* of the response $y_t.$

Comment: @whuber Yes sorry I have made a mistake on my previous message.  Thank you !